# Lubuntu 18.04 can't SSH to Cisco Router: no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1

Tags: networking, ssh, lubuntu, cisco

I'm not sure if this problem caused by Lubuntu or Cisco Router side.

```
Lubuntu = 192.168.1.100
Cisco Router = 192.168.1.1
```

SSH from Lubuntu to Cisco Router

```
user@linux:~$ ssh -V
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
user@linux:~$

user@linux:~$ ssh admin@192.168.1.1
Unable to negotiate with 192.168.1.1 port 22: no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
user@linux:~$
```

This is on Cisco Router side

```
R1#
*Mar  1 01:41:19.631: SSH2 0: no matching cipher found: client chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,
R1#
```

SSH Verbose

```
user@linux:~$ ssh 192.168.1.1 -l admin -v
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.1 [192.168.1.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version Cisco-1.25
debug1: match: Cisco-1.25 pat Cisco-1.* compat 0x60000000
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.1.1:22 as 'admin'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: (no match)
Unable to negotiate with 192.168.1.1 port 22: no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
user@linux:~$
```

More Cisco Log

```
R1(config)#ip ssh logging events
R1(config)#
R1(config)#
*Mar  1 01:56:21.723: SSH2 0: no matching cipher found: client chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,
R1(config)#
*Mar  1 01:56:21.723: %SSH-5-SSH2_SESSION: SSH2 Session request from 192.168.1.100 (tty = 0) using crypto cipher '', hmac '' Failed
*Mar  1 01:56:21.723: %SSH-5-SSH2_CLOSE: SSH2 Session from 192.168.1.100 (tty = 0) for user '' using crypto cipher '', hmac '' closed
R1(config)#
```

What is the problem here and how to fix it?

**Update 1**

I've tried these as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1222851/769117) but it didn't solve the problem

```
user@linux:~$ ssh -oKexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 192.168.1.1
Unable to negotiate with 192.168.1.1 port 22: no matching cipher found. Their offer: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
user@linux:~$ 

user@linux:~$ ssh -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss 192.168.1.1
Unable to negotiate with 192.168.1.1 port 22: no matching cipher found. Their offer: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
user@linux:~$
```

Comment: What authorization method(s) are you using?

Comment: @OrganicMarble, I've updated my question with more log. Hopefully one of them will answer your question. If not, let me know what kind of `authorization method(s)` are you looking here.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the Cisco router. Ubuntu's `ssh` client proposes a default set of modern and secure encryptions and the router proposes another set (with [legacy algorithms](http://www.openssh.com/legacy.html)) and they have none in common.

You can force `ssh` to add the weak legacy algorithms to its list of proposals:

From the command line:

```
ssh -oKexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 192.168.1.1
```

or adding the option to `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host 192.168.1.1
  KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
```

As [explained here](https://www.openssh.com/legacy.html) (you have other solutions there), that might be not be enough and you might have to enable `ssh-dss` too.

```
ssh -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss 192.168.1.1
```

or adding the option to `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host 192.168.1.1
  HostKeyAlgorithms +ssh-dss
```

Comment: `ssh -oKexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 192.168.1.1` doesn't work.

Comment: _does it now work_ : do you get an error message? Also, please note I added another option to the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately not, I've updated the full log above. See `Update 1`

Answer (score 1):

try this one, you did not specify the cypher to use

```
ssh -oKexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 -c aes128-cbc -l username 192.168.1.1
```